# Carroll's interpretation of 1-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

This question is crossposted from [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/503102/carrolls-interpretation-of-1-forms).

---

Carroll writes in his Spacetime and Geometry book on page 68 that

> "[...] in fact, however, we could just as well have begun with an intrinsic definition of one-forms and used that to define vectors as the dual space. Roughly speaking, the space of one-forms at $p$ is equivalent to the space of all functions that vanish at $p$ and have the same second partial derivatives. In fact, doing it that way is more fundamental, if anything, since we can provide intrinsic definitions of all $q$-forms (totally antisymmetric tensors with $q$ lower indices), etc."

Could somebody explain this *equivalency* in a bit more detail?

---

When I asked this question on [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/503102/carrolls-interpretation-of-1-forms) I got several replies but the more I thought of the consensus answer, namely that it must be a "typo" the less satisfied I was. So I wrote to Prof. Carroll and asked him directly but his answer was quite laconic and cryptic "Nope, it is correct. If the first derivatives were the same, they'd be the same one-forms."

Now I am totally confused, and I have another question: what does Carroll mean by this?

Comment: It would be easier if you include the email to carroll, so that we understand their reply better.

Comment: May be he means the definition of $T^*_pM$ as $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$, where $\mathfrak m$ is the maximal ideal of the algebra of smooth germs at $p$.

Yuo can find this point of view in Wedhorn's book Manifolds, sheaves and cohomology.

Comment: In fact, this is how you define tangent spaces in algebraic geometry. You first define the cotangent space $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ and then the tangent space is defined as the dual space $(\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2)^\vee$ of $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$.

Comment: The fact that you take the quotient modulo $\mathfrak m^2$ means that you are effectively killing whatever two germs which have the same second derivative.

Comment: What was probably meant is that one begins with the set of all (smooth) functions that vanish at $p$ and then one defines two such functions to be equivalent if they have the same second partial derivatives at $p$.  The resulting equivalence classes correspond, in a one-to-one manner, with the one-forms at $p$.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that my comment is equivalent to @JackozeeHakkiuz's, but it takes some work to show that, if a (smooth) function has vanishing second partial derivatives at $p$ then it's in the square of the ideal of functions vanishing at $p$.